# Selenium Webdriver + Ruby regex: Can I use regex with find_element?

Tags: ruby, regex, webdriver

I am trying to click an element that changes per each order like so

```
edit_div_123

edit_div_124

edit_div_xxx

xxx = any three numbers
```

I have tried using regex like so:

```
@driver.find_element(:css, "#edit_order_#{\d*} > div.submit > button[name=\"commit\"]").click 

@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[(@id = "edit_order_#{\d*}")]//button").click
```

Is this possible? Any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use Regexp, like the other answers have indicated.

Instead, you can use a nifty CSS Selector trick:

```
@driver.find_element(:css, "[id^=\"edit_order_\"] > div.submit > button[name=\"commit\"]").click
```

Using:

- ^= indicates to find the element with the value beginning with your criteria.
- *= says the criteria should be found anywhere within the element's value
- $= indicates to find the element with with your criteria at the end of the value.
- ~= allows you to find the element based on a single criteria when the actual value has multiple space-seperated list of values.

Take a look at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/ for some more info on other neat CSS tricks you should add to your utility belt!

Answer (score 2):

You have no provided any html fragment that you are working on. Hence my answer is just based on the limited inputs provided your question.

I don't think WebDriver APIs support regex for locating elements. However, you can achieve what you want using just plain XPath as follows:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'edit_div_')]//button
```

**Explanation**: Above xpath will try to search all `<button>` nodes present under all elements whose `id` attribute starts with string  `edit_div_`

In short, you can use `starts-with()` xpath function in order to match element with id format as `edit_div_   followed by any number of characters`

Comment: This worked for me (:xpath, "//*button[starts-with(@id, 'edit_div_')]").click

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not.

But you should do something like this:

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
  var re = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s+)' + className + '(?:\\s+|$)');
  return re.test(element.className);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[contains(@href, 'person')]").click
```